# to give multiple values to thymeleaf attribute

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a requirement to give multiple values to thymeleaf attribute. In my view page, it is a combination of angular, thymleaf with spring mvc.

```
<div id="zipLookup" ng-controller="AddressManagementCtrl" data-th-attr="data-data=*{primary.zipcode}, *{primary.county}, *{primary.city}, *{primary.street1}, *{primary.street2}">
```

which is throwing error

`TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence. "data-data=*{primary.postCode},*{primary.county},*{primary.city},*{primary.street1},*{primary.street2}`"

It is clear that the syntax is incorrect, but can some one suggest me the correct way to implement this.
The intention is the after document parse, it should look something like this:

```
data-data='{
  "zipCode": "90292",
  "state": "CA",
  "county": "--",
  "city": "Marina",
  "addressLine1": "...",
  "addressLine2": "..."
}'
```

Here zipcode, state,county,city,addressline1,addressline2 are properties of spring bean.

I'm kind of new to `thymeleaf` and `angular-js`. Can someone help? Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Can you try to put `data-data=...` into quotes ? `data-th-attr="data-data='......'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
data-th-attr="data-data= + *{primary.zipcode} + ',' + *{primary.county}"
```

The output HTML would be:

```
data-th-attr="data-data=somezip,somecountry"
```

I suggest however that you consider the possibility of preparing the string in the Controller (possibly using a JSON library like Jackson) and passing that to the model (which will then just you use it directly).

Comment: thanks for the immediate response, the template engine process good with slight modification , that is remove single quotes to data-data=

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer with your suggestion. It would be in the benefit of future readers if you accept the answer as correct (if indeed it solves your problem). Thanks

Comment: thanks for response, the template engine process good with slight changes, that is data-th-attr="data-data=*{primary.postCode} + ',' + *{primary.county} + ',' + *{primary.city} + ',' + *{primary.street1} + ',' + *{primary.street2}" and the parsed html is data-data="91320,06111,newburypark,3200N, newbury park,CA But I'm able to see this html parse out when I inspect the document. these values are not displayed on actual form. I think there is some angularjs issue that has to be handled. any idea how data-data='{..}' displays  data on form or view?

Comment: @user3681484 Unfortunately I have not worked with AngularJS (although it's on the list of Todo's :)) so I can't really help you with why the form is not being displayed